# How Can I View Open PST Files In Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell, microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

Is it possible to view a list of PST files which have been loaded in to Outlook? Preferably from inside Outlook rather than having to run any kind of script (I'm sure this could be done with PowerShell somehow).

Some research and a scan through the menus in Outlook don't seem to yield any results and I haven't come across any similar questions on Stack Exchange.

Look forward to responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on Data Files tab in Account settings: **File -> Account Settings -> Data Files**.